# C++ to Delphi: variable in FOR loop with assigned declaration

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

What is the equivalent in Delphi for this **`for`** loop around [`ChildWindowFromPoint()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-childwindowfrompoint) from this C++ code:

```cpp
HWND  hWnd;
POINT point;

...

for (HWND currHwnd = hWnd;;)
{
    hWnd = currHwnd;
    ScreenToClient(currHwnd, &point);
    currHwnd = ChildWindowFromPoint(currHwnd, point);
    if (!currHwnd || currHwnd == hWnd)
        break;
}
```

My attempt was this, but I'm not sure that it is right:

```pascal
var
  hWndWindow, currHwnd: HWND;
  MousePoint: TPoint;

...

while True do
begin
  currHwnd := hWndWindow;
  hWndWindow := currHwnd;
  ScreenToClient(currHwnd, MousePoint);
  currHwnd := ChildWindowFromPoint(currHwnd, MousePoint);

  if (currHwnd = 0) or (currHwnd = hWndWindow) then
    Break;
end;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your translation is *almost* correct, but you did make *one* mistake. You need to move the initial assignment of `currHwnd` outside of the `while` loop:

```pascal
var
  hWndWindow, currHwnd: HWND;
  MousePoint: TPoint;

...

currHwnd := hWndWindow; // <-- moved here!
while True do
begin
  hWndWindow := currHwnd;
  ScreenToClient(currHwnd, MousePoint);
  currHwnd := ChildWindowFromPoint(currHwnd, MousePoint);

  if (currHwnd = 0) or (currHwnd = hWndWindow) then
    Break;
end;
```

Per [`for` loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for) on cppreference.com:

> *formal syntax:*
>
> *attr*(optional) **for (** *init-statement* *condition*(optional) **;** *iteration_expression*(optional) **)** *statement*
>
> *informal syntax:*
>
> *attr*(optional) **for (** *declaration-or-expression*(optional) **;** *declaration-or-expression*(optional) **;** *expression*(optional) **)** *statement*
>
> *attr*(C++11) - any number of attributes
>
> *init-statement* - either
>
> - an expression statement (which may be a *null statement* ";")
> - a simple declaration, typically a declaration of a loop counter variable with initializer, but it may declare arbitrary many variables
>
>   Note that any *init-statement* must end with a semicolon ;, which is why it is often described informally as an expression or a declaration followed by a semicolon.
>
> *condition* - either
>
> - an expression which is contextually convertible to bool. This expression is evaluated before each iteration, and if it yields false, the loop is exited.
> - declaration of a single variable with a brace-or-equals initializer. the initializer is evaluated before each iteration, and if the value of the declared variable converts to false, the loop is exited.
>
> *iteration_expression* - any expression, which is executed after every iteration of the loop and before re-evaluating *condition*. Typically, this is the expression that increments the loop counter
>
> *statement* - any statement, typically a compound statement, which is the body of the loop
>
> **Explanation**
>
> The above syntax produces code equivalent to:
>
> ```c
> {
>     init_statement 
>     while ( condition ) { 
>         statement 
>         iteration_expression ; 
>     }
> }
> ```

That being said, I would have translated the C++ loop into a Delphi `repeat..until` loop (and written the C++ code to use a `do..while` loop):

```cpp
HWND hWnd;
POINT point;

...

HWND currHwnd = hWnd;
do
{
    hWnd = currHwnd;
    ScreenToClient(currHwnd, &point);
    currHwnd = ChildWindowFromPoint(currHwnd, point);
}
while (currHwnd && currHwnd != hWnd);
```

```pascal
var
  hWndWindow, currHwnd: HWND;
  MousePoint: TPoint;

...

currHwnd := hWndWindow;
repeat
  hWndWindow := currHwnd;
  ScreenToClient(currHwnd, MousePoint);
  currHwnd := ChildWindowFromPoint(currHwnd, MousePoint);
until (currHwnd = 0) or (currHwnd = hWndWindow);
```